# Extracting the last sequence of numbers in excel

Tags: string, excel, sequence, data-extraction, vba

I have a list of addresses from which I need to extract the last sequence of numbers (zip code). I'm looking for a general expression from which I can extract the zip codes from addresses from all over the world. I would have to tweak the expression in order for it to work for each country, or for a group of countries, I assume.

I'm trying to write a formula in excel that can recognise the last digit in a string, and from that, extract the numbers immediately before that last digit and stoping whenever it reaches a non-integer. Below I have an example of an address and the formula I've come up with (in E26), but I'm looking for something more compact:

*National Institute of Pharmaceutical Education and Research (NIPER), Phase X, Sector 67, SAS Nagar, Punjab, 160062, India.*

```
=MID(E26, MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(E26,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(E26))),1))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(E26))))+1)-6, 6)
```

The first part of recognizing the last digit is working fine, the problem is to recognize the beggining of the sequence, at least in cases where there's also street numbers within the string (such as in this case). This is why I'm subtacting -6 to the position where the last digit was found, since I know the lenght of the zip code in this particular country. However, it may not be the case for all countries.

Plus there are cases, where there's a space between the sequence such as: *160 062*. Also, they won't always have delimeters that I could use to extract the zip codes, hence, the reason why a need an algorithm for this.

I was wondering if there's a nitter way to do this? I would be open for VBA.  Thanks for your help!

Best regards,
Antonio

Comment: "*I need an algorithm for this.*" Well if there is no pattern like always the same delimiters or always a specific amount of characters or something similar then there is no algorithm. You might be able to use Regular Expressions for that in combination with VBA but you will still need to find a pattern for that. Therefore I vote "too broad to answer".

Comment: You want an algorithm which will pull out the zip code/postal code in _any_ country?  Keeping in mind that each person in a country may write their address differently - the zip code may be at the beginning; not because it's meant to be there but because that's how the person wrote it.  When you find the algorithm please share!

Comment: I guess it will be difficult to obtain a general expression for all zip codes but i will be able to use a variation of my previous expression  to extract them based on the format and lenght of the different zip codes around the world. If you have any suggestions please let me know :)

Comment: @antoniogouveia Well since you are the only one who knows how your data looks like you are probably the only one who can find a pattern for it.

Comment: The addresses would be similar to one I posted above. The postal code appears always in the end. That formula works almost perfectly for indian, japanese and chinese addresses and I have around 3,000 of addresses combined from those countries. I will only need to tweak it for other countries. I guess that will work.

Comment: Well "*similar to one I posted*" is nothing that we can use to help you. We don't have a crystal ball.

Comment: _The postal code appears always in the end_.  Your example has _India_ at the end.

Comment: Maybe pass the addresses through a service like Postcode Anywhere (now called PCA Direct)?  No idea what their international searching is like though.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to have them isolated from the string first?

Comment: I found an expression with similar result as the one I've posted above but with the advantage of being possible to input the needed format and lenght for the sequence to extract, if anyone is interested:

=TEXT(LOOKUP(10^8,MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","x"),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)-7)),8)+0),"00000000")